# Hosting Firebase on your own server

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm an iOS developer with little backend knowledge. I've been using Firebase to create the backends for my apps for over a year now and it's worked great. My latest client wants an app with a relatively simple backend, which I would have no problem creating with Firebase, but due to their privacy policy they require that all collected data be stored on their in-house servers. Interestingly they have a server room with IT techs, but no developers.

My question is: is there a way to host Firebase on your own server instead of using one of Google's? I've searched around for the answer and unfortunately the consensus seems to be no, however, I have seen a few posts from years ago saying that this service is coming in the future. Does anyone know if its here yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this service is not here yet. One alternative you might consider is Parse Server - an open service, host yourself, replacement for Parse.

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server

https://www.raywenderlich.com/146736/parse-server-tutorial-ios